# Clone and set local repository config in one command

Tags: git

I have a script that clones all of my organizations repos (100+). Problem is that they all inherit my global git config, but I really want to have my organization email in the cloned repos local config. Is there a way to specify this on cloning, or do I have to script it?

My global `.gitconfig`

```
[user]
    email = myname@gmail.com
```

What I want in my organizations repos

```
[user]
    email = myname@organization.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably should've read the documentation on clone better. There actually is an option for this: `--config`, which sets local configuration directly after it's cloned.

```
 git clone --config user.email=myname@organization.com git@github.name/repo.git
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always have a custom config by pointing `GIT_CONFIG` to another config file, like:

```
export GIT_CONFIG=~/.gitconfig-work
```

Once you are done you can switch back to your normal config:

```
export GIT_CONFIG=~/.gitconfig
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is similar to what I have used, but I'll often forget to switch back, and do commits with the wrong config. Looking for a way to avoid that :) I can of course script it, but would be nice to have a one liner for it. Something like `git clone git@github.com:name/repo.git --copy-config ~/.gitconfig-work`

Comment: True, but even that part can be forgotten. You can have an one liner like: `GIT_CONFIG=~/.gitconfig-work git clone git@github.com:name/repo.git`